# Intervene "Out Of Memory"

Tags: xml, linq-to-xml, out-of-memory

I'm importing a Xml document by using XDocument. If the file reaches a certain size, the runtime throws an OutOfMemoryException. I already know why it happens and it's okay with me.

While trying to find out the maximum capacity of the file I figured, I must have enough memory for importing larger files. Somehow I don't .. :-) I wonder why.

In my case the file is about 1.3 Gig. When I start my process the available memory is about 5.3 Gig and it goes up to 6.8 during the import. After a while it throws the above mentioned exception, although my machine has 16 Gigs, which means there are more then 9 Gigs free.

How can I intervene this behaviour? What's the reason behind it? I compiled against x86 architecture. Is that an issue?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when you compile against x86 the process can only address ~4 gb of RAM.  Change your process to be x64 and it will be able to address all available ram.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just noticed it, while I was writing the text.